# Tensorflow with R and Anaconda - error "Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL"

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

There are some answers to this question in a Python environment, but the solutions did not work for my RStudio environment. Here is my code:

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
use_condaenv("tf")
train_dir = "C:/training_images/"
train_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)
validation_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)
train_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    train_datagen,
    target_size = c(150, 150),
    batch_size = 20,
    class_mode = "binary"
  )
batch <- generator_next(train_generator)
```

The code works until the last "batch" line where it explodes like this:

```
Error in py_iter_next(it, completed) : 
  ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL.

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Users\mory3\ANACON~1\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 104, in __next__
    return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mory3\ANACON~1\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 116, in next
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "C:\Users\mory3\ANACON~1\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 230, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    interpolation=self.interpolation)
  File "C:\Users\mory3\ANACON~1\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 108, in load_img
    raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
```

R version 3.6.1
Conda version 4.7
Python version 3.7

Comment: Furthermore, trying to run the `fit_generator` function fails for the same reason, so I can't run the model!

Comment: A full conda update via `conda update --all` worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem
After a few hours of looking, I came up with a solution that worked for me. 
I used this code for solving the PIL problem. I tried using anaconda prompt but this code worked in r for me...

```
reticulate::py_install("pillow",env=tf)
```

I came up with this error next...

```
loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.4.2 but source was compiled with: 7.6.0.
```

Make sure you have the correct cudnn version installed. For me it was CUDA 10 with 7.6.0 cudnn with 10. The output of the error will tell you which one to use.
Make sure you have cleaned any extra path variables that are in your environmental variables from installing previous versions.

```
I'm using windows 10
gpu = GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design
R - 3.6.1
tensorflow = 1.13
python = 3.7
anaconda = Anaconda3–2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe
```

Comment: I ran the first command of this answer for the identical case. Installed Pillow -7.1.2 using my anaconda local installation and python 3.6. However, that did not have any impact on the initial error. My laptop does not have a GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling Anaconda altogether, which made troubleshooting the remaining errors in the Python connection to R *much* simpler.

Comment: I've never tried running gpu version of keras and tensorflow in r without anaconda but I would imagine it's set up to do that lol I've always had anaconda with the hopes of learning python one day but haven't gotten around to it yet

Comment: I hear you @FrosyFeet456, it's easy to get frustrated with the version inconsistencies of so many packages. I systematically updated every component but a full update of conda solved my system's troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with "Deep Learning with R" CNN example on Win7. I solved it like this:

1. I added Anaconda3 paths to PATH. In my case it was Windows so paths were like that:
   C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin  By default there were no paths to conda in $PATH.
2. installed pillow (it contains PIL) to python with:
   pip install pillow
3. configured r-reticulate.
   This answer [Could not import PIL.Image even if Pillow already installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612703/could-not-import-pil-image-even-if-pillow-already-installed) helped me. I had pillow already but conda environment wasn't configured properly so pillow wasn't visible.

Also install Nvidia CUDA if you don't have it - you need it too for tensorflow.